# Can't install MacTeX error on validating packages

Tags: errors, installing, mactex

I am trying to install MacTex that i downloaded from http://www.tug.org/mactex/ but when i am installing it gets a error message "The installation failed" i don't know what to do.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: You can look at the log of the installation: press "Command-L" at the first installation screen  and the log window will appear (there's a menu entry, anyway, for it).

Comment: Also, have you [checked your download](http://www.tug.org/mactex/downloading.html)?

Comment: You guys are too prompt to decide if a question is unlikely to help others, I had the exact same issue, came here, tried the proposed solution and it worked. It's actually even stated here: https://tug.org/mactex/downloading.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you all for your answer, lockstep i will keep it in mind!

My problem was resolved simply with instead of downloading the .pkg from the Google Chrome download it from Safari.